# How can I replace a string in multiple files with a value from a list, sequentially in Powershell?

Tags: string, powershell, replace

Lets say I have a bunch of text files with people's names, that all have this as the content:

number

I want to replace "number" with a value from a CSV or text file, sequentially, and based on the file name. CSV has two columns, name and number:

```
Joe 5551011000
Gary 5551011001
Clark 5551011002
```

So I want to find the text file named Joe, and replace the "number" with "5551011000", and the text file named Gary, and replace "number" with "5551011001".

Thank you!

I didn't get too far:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\test\*.txt" -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    (Get-Content $_) -Replace 'changeme', 'MyValue' | Set-Content $_
}
```

This gets me party there, but I don't know how to find a specific file, then replace "number" in that file with the correct value that matches the name.

I also tried a different approach, with manual entry, and it works, but I need it to just be automated:

```
get-childitem c:\Marriott -recurse -include *.txt | 
 select -expand fullname |
  foreach {
  $new = Read-Host 'What is the new value you want for ' $_
            (Get-Content $_) -replace 'number',$new |
             Set-Content $_
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your CSV to a hashtable, then this gets pretty simple.

```
$ReplaceHT = @{}
Import-Csv c:\path\to\file.csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header 'FileName','Number' | ForEach-Object {$ReplaceHT.add($_.FileName,$_.Number)}
Get-ChildItem c:\Marriott -recurse -include *.txt -PipelineVariable 'File'|Where{$_.name -in $ReplaceHT.Keys} |ForEach-Object{
    (Get-Content $File.FullName) -replace 'changeme', $ReplaceHT[$File.Name] | Set-Content $File.FullName
    }
```